# Is logarithm integrable? essentially bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I've calculated $H\mathbb{1}_{(a,b)}$ for $(a,b)\subset(1,\infty)$ for easy calculations, but it doesn't matter, i.e.
$H1_{(a,b)}(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\ln|\frac{x-b}{x-a}|$, my task was to show that is not in $L^1$ nor in $L^\infty$. Is it? I thought that (outside of x=a) it is integrable.. It is not bounded in one point, how to show that it's measure theoretic properties are s.t. it's singularity at x=a "has a non zero measure"? is somehow big.

Oh.. it has two singularities - x=a and x=b.

Part of my comment:

Yeah, you're right. Ok so my hypothesis is: in x=b this 0-singularity of logarithm wins and for that reason whole function is not in $L^\infty$, and in x=a this $\infty-$ singularity wins for that reason it's not in $L^1$. What do you think about it? How to show those properties (esp. with $L^\infty$) of log or where could I read about it?

best

Comment: $\ln(x)$ on $(0,a)$ for any $a>0$ is in every $L^p$ except $L^\infty$. Thus in some sense a logarithmic singularity is "quite mild".

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Ok so my hypothesis is: in x=b this 0-singularity of logarithm wins and for that reason whole function is not in $L^\infty$, and in x=a this $\infty-$ singularity wins for that reason it's not in $L^1$. What do you think about it? How to show those properties (esp. with $L^\infty$) of log or where could I read about it?

Comment: The $x=a$ and $x=b$ singularities of your function are of exactly the same character (don't forget your log rules).

Comment: yeah, that was silly. still don't know why it shouldn't be $L^1$. Thanks for all your answers!

Comment: It *is* $L^1$, that's what I was saying...

Comment: Ok that's what I thought at first, but I don't know what my 'taks giver' wanted. Thanks!